# How to get the max/min value for multiple indices

Tags: python, max

I have a large dataset with multiple lines and want to return the largest value for `index[2]` out of all lines. So in the example below I want 20 to be returned. The following just prints the value at the index and not the maxima.

```
1,"Goroka",10,"Pacific"
2,"Madang",20,"Pacific"
3,"Mount Hagen",5,"Pacific"

for line in data.readlines():
    splitLine = line.split(",") # Split line on ,
    ID = splitLine[0]
    name = splitLine[1]
    no = splitLine[2]
    ocean = splitLine[4]

print max(no)
```

Comment: Since you are reading it line by line, you can simply find the maxima in the loop by comparing `no` with current maxima

Comment: Is your data in a file or is it a multiline string? Are you only looking for the max or are you dealing with this data in some fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is saved in a .txt file, and since you're using Python, you may try pandas.

If your example data is saved as "**data.txt**" in your working directory, try:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_table('data.txt', sep=',', header=None)
data.columns = ['col_' + str(no) for no in range(0, len(data.columns))]  # add column names (though not necessarily)
max_value = max(data['col_2'])
```

I suppose the `max_value` is what you want.

Comment: How can I get the accompanying data on the `max_value` line?

Comment: Use `data[data.col_2 == max_value]` to retrieve the whole line.
data[data.col_2 == max_value].col_0.iloc[0]
data[data.col_2 == max_value].col_1.iloc[0]
data[data.col_2 == max_value].col_3.iloc[0]

Answer (score 1):

Build the maximum as you go:

```
maxno = 0
for line in data.readlines():
    splitLine = line.split(",") # Split line on ,
    ID = splitLine[0]
    name = splitLine[1]
    no = splitLine[2]
    ocean = splitLine[4]
    if no > maxno:
        maxno = no

 print maxno
```

Comment: nb. this assumes that `no` will always be > 0. Setting `maxno` to `None` will work with negative values (in python 2, not python3).

Comment: As you stated, no can also be -ve. Maxno = 0/None both worked. I reversed this with < to find the min but only return 0, which is incorrect.

Comment: I just visually checked and the result isn't the max.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data that looks line that in a string in memory:

```
>>> print txt
1,"Goroka",10,"Pacific"
2,"Madang",20,"Pacific"
3,"Mount Hagen",5,"Pacific"
```

You can use `max` or `min` with a lambda key function to find the line with the max or min value of the third csv field:

```
>>> max(txt.splitlines(), key=lambda line:int(line.split(',')[2]))
'2,"Madang",20,"Pacific"'
```

Or, for a min:

```
>>> min(txt.splitlines(), key=lambda line:int(line.split(',')[2]))
'3,"Mount Hagen",5,"Pacific"'
```

Then parse that line if you are just looking for the third value.

Using exactly the same approach, you can sort data like that to get the max n values or min n values:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(sorted(txt.splitlines(), key=lambda line:int(line.split(',')[2])))
3,"Mount Hagen",5,"Pacific"
1,"Goroka",10,"Pacific"
2,"Madang",20,"Pacific"
```

If the data is in a file, use the general idiom of line-by-line parsing with same approach:

```
with open(your_file) as f:
    max(f, key=lambda line:int(line.split(',')[2]))
```

In general, it is better to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for such data in a file. It is also better to avoid using `file.readlines()` to get the contents of the file versus iterating over the file with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max(data,key=func)` key functionality to find the max from the complex data set. Assuming you have the data in a list of list.

```
test = [[1,"Goroka",10,"Pacific"],[2,"Madang",20,"Pacific"],[3,"Mount Hagen",5,"Pacific"]]
data = max (test,key=lambda x: x[2]) ## or use min
print data[2]
```

Answer (score -2):

I was going to suggest that you save the data in an array. For example:

```
data = [[1,"Goroka",10,"Pacific"],[2,"Madang",20,"Pacific"],[3,"Mount Hagen,5,"Pacific"]]
```

You can then get what you are after like this:

```
for item in data:
    maxno = item[2]
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it

Comment: This is no different to their original method